# How to adding sender's name to order comments in Magento2 admin?

Tags: admin, magento2.2

How to adding senders name to order comments in the magento2 admin panel. I don't know how to implement this task. Can you please help me? The below screenshot is my required output screenshot.https://prnt.sc/jtx9di

Comment: You mean customer name?

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, add by admin username. Can you please help me?

Comment: Logged in admin username? Or the name of admin who comment there? Also this is only for admin or on frontend as well?

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, I want to display name of admin who  comeent there.

Comment: Hi @  Sukumar Gorai, please find the link. https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-senders-name-order-comments/ .This is the magento1 and I want to display these in magento2

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, I want to display only admin.

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, Can you please help me with this task?

Comment: Give me few minutes I ll share you an answer.

Comment: Hi @Sukumar Gorai, OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the following file:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AddComment.php

After that inject \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session like below:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->authSession = $authSession;
    ...
}
```

Under execute function add the below line:

```
$username = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
$append = " (by ".$username.")";
$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment($data['comment'].$append, $data['status']);
```

In place of

```
$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment($data['comment'], $data['status']);
```

All done. After that you can edit anything from admin will show the admin username to the comments.

If you want to edit the core file AddComment.php then you can add the following code to your AddComment.php. But this is not a good practice to modify core files directly. Best way is to override that file and work accordingly.
Code for AddComment.php:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender;

use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class AddComment extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Sales::comment';

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $_fileFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface
     */
    protected $_translateInline;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $resultLayoutFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory
     */
    protected $resultRawFactory;

    /**
     * @var OrderManagementInterface
     */
    protected $orderManagement;

    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    protected $authSession;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ) {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry,$fileFactory,$translateInline,$resultPageFactory,$resultJsonFactory,$resultLayoutFactory,$resultRawFactory,$orderManagement,$orderRepository,$logger);
    }

    /**
     * Add order comment action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $order = $this->_initOrder();
        if ($order) {
            try {
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('history');
                if (empty($data['comment']) && $data['status'] == $order->getDataByKey('status')) {
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Please enter a comment.'));
                }

                $notify = isset($data['is_customer_notified']) ? $data['is_customer_notified'] : false;
                $visible = isset($data['is_visible_on_front']) ? $data['is_visible_on_front'] : false;

                $username = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
                $append = " (by ".$username.")";

                $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment($data['comment'].$append, $data['status']);
                $history->setIsVisibleOnFront($visible);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified($notify);
                $history->save();

                $comment = trim(strip_tags($data['comment']));

                $order->save();
                /** @var OrderCommentSender $orderCommentSender */
                $orderCommentSender = $this->_objectManager
                    ->create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender::class);

                $orderCommentSender->send($order, $notify, $comment);

                return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $response = ['error' => true, 'message' => $e->getMessage()];
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $response = ['error' => true, 'message' => __('We cannot add order history.')];
            }
            if (is_array($response)) {
                $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
                $resultJson->setData($response);
                return $resultJson;
            }
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('sales/*/');
    }
}
```

After the changes run the below commands:

> bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

(if needed)(-f if developer mode and default mode enabled)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, how to overriding the file I don't know. Can you please help me this task?

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, I have changed to file path  vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AddComment.php In this file I have added your code but Comments was not creating .

Comment: If you are adding the same code to core file then you need to modify the AddComment.php. I am adding AddComment.php file to my answer.

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, Good morning. It is not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you try to post new comments?

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, I have created app/code/webkul/Hello/etc/di.xml code below.<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order" type="Webkul\Hello\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddComment" />
</config>

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, I have created app/code/webkul/Hello/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AddComment.php inside your code I am adding. But admin username does not display in admin. Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you try it by adding it to core once? Only for try

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, It is working on the core file. But how can override that AddComment.php  file?

Comment: You are working with webkul test right? Allow me few hours I ll update you.

Comment: Hi@Sukumar Gorai, Yaa. I have the working webkul test .

Comment: Did you create the complete module? Is it showing under app/etc/config.php ?

Comment: Hi@Sukumar Gorai, I have to override the core file successfully. It is working. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I have to click green tick mark.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this with the plugin and it is the easiest and fastest way to do this.

Define Plugin in `di.xml`

```
<!--  add admin name in comment  -->
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order">
    <plugin name="AddAdminNameToComment" type="Tecksky\Custom\Plugin\Sales\Model\Order" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

Add Plugin file `Order.php`

```
    <?php
namespace Tecksky\Custom\Plugin\Sales\Model;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderStatusHistoryInterface;

class Order{

    protected $authSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ){
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
    }

    /**
     * Add a comment to order status history.
     *
     * add admin name in comment
     *
     * @param string $comment
     * @param bool|string $status
     * @param bool $isVisibleOnFront
     */
    public function beforeAddCommentToStatusHistory(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $subject, $comment, $status, $isVisibleOnFront)
    {
        $username = $this->authSession->getUser()->getFirstName()." ".$this->authSession->getUser()->getLastName();
        $comment = $comment . " <span style='color:deeppink'>(By ".$username.")</span>";
        return [$comment, $status, $isVisibleOnFront];
    }
}
```

add span tag in escape HTML using theme files.

```
\app\design\adminhtml\Local\backend-custom\Magento_Sales\templates\order\view\history.phtml

\app\design\frontend\Local\argento-stripes-custom\Magento_Sales\templates\order\order_comments.phtml
```

Change `<?= $block->escapeHtml(..., [..., 'span']) ?>`

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_historyItem->getComment(), ['b', 'br', 'strong', 'i', 'u', 'a', 'span']) ?>


<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getComment(), ['b', 'br', 'strong', 'i', 'u', 'a', 'span']) ?>
```

> **Frontend:**

[image: frontend order comment]

> **Backend**

[image: admin order comment]

Thank you.

Comment: Where are these two files?

Comment: \app\design\adminhtml\Local\backend-custom\Magento_Sales\templates\order\view\history.phtml

\app\design\frontend\Local\argento-stripes-custom\Magento_Sales\templates\order\order_comments.phtml