# I want to show the admin user on, change order status in bulk or single order

Tags: event-observer, plugin, order-grid, admin-user

> **I want to show the admin user name on change order status in order comment history in bulk or single order, using a single event or plugin
> Magento 2.3.5p1 Community edition**

**Any help highly appreciated**

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adding sender's name to order comments in Magento2 admin?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229532/how-to-adding-senders-name-to-order-comments-in-magento2-admin)

Answer (score 1):

There is an already answer for this question. Please refer the link

[How to adding sender's name to order comments in Magento2 admin?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229532/how-to-adding-senders-name-to-order-comments-in-magento2-admin)

Below is a working sample tested in Magento 2.3.5-p1

**app/code/[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddComment" type="[Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddComment" />
</config>
```

**app/code/[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AddComment.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;


use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class AddComment
 */
class AddComment extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
     /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Sales::comment';

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $_fileFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface
     */
    protected $_translateInline;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $resultLayoutFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory
     */
    protected $resultRawFactory;

    /**
     * @var OrderManagementInterface
     */
    protected $orderManagement;

    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    protected $authSession;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ) {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry,$fileFactory,$translateInline,$resultPageFactory,$resultJsonFactory,$resultLayoutFactory,$resultRawFactory,$orderManagement,$orderRepository,$logger);
    }


    /**
     * Add order comment action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        
        $order = $this->_initOrder();
        if ($order) {
            try {
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('history');
                if (empty($data['comment']) && $data['status'] == $order->getDataByKey('status')) {
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                        __('The comment is missing. Enter and try again.')
                    );
                }

                $notify = $data['is_customer_notified'] ?? false;
                $visible = $data['is_visible_on_front'] ?? false;

                if ($notify && !$this->_authorization->isAllowed(self::ADMIN_SALES_EMAIL_RESOURCE)) {
                    $notify = false;
                }

                $username = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
                $append = " (by ".$username.")";

                $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment($data['comment'].$append, $data['status']);
                $history->setIsVisibleOnFront($visible);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified($notify);
                $history->save();

                

                $comment = trim(strip_tags($data['comment']));

                $order->save();
                /** @var OrderCommentSender $orderCommentSender */
                $orderCommentSender = $this->_objectManager
                    ->create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender::class);

                $orderCommentSender->send($order, $notify, $comment);

                return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $response = ['error' => true, 'message' => $e->getMessage()];
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $response = ['error' => true, 'message' => __('We cannot add order history.')];
            }
            if (is_array($response)) {
                $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
                $resultJson->setData($response);
                return $resultJson;
            }
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('sales/*/');
        return parent::execute();
    }
}
```

Run the below commands after modifying the files

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: not working, i tried!

Comment: @MuneshJalwani Updated the answer

Comment: @RintoGeorge Hi, I tried this solution, but I get this error
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'ADMIN_SALES_EMAIL_RESOURCE' in /Users/jonathanhelvey/ULM-NewSite/httpdocs/app/code/UpperLimits/AddAdminNametoComment/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AddComment.php:126 Stack trace: #0 /Users/jonathanhelvey/ULM-NewSite/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108): UpperLimits\AddAdminNameToComment\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddComment-`

Comment: When I checkmark "Notify Customer By Email" Is when Error is thrown.
`NewSite/httpdocs/app/code/UpperLimits/AddAdminNametoComment/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AddComment.php on line 126`

Also, Posting comment does work if I do Not checkmark "Notify Customer By Email", however, after posting comment I have to refresh page, for it to show, otherwise notes is missing until browser refresh. Just curious if you know a solution to help fix. Thank you for any help.

Comment: @Jonathan  Which exact version of Magento you are using?

Comment: Magento 2.3.5 pt-2

Comment: @RintoGeorge, I set 'ADMIN_SALES_EMAIL_RESOURCE' and that fixed the error. However, when you hit 'Submit Comment Button" it will be a blank white screen until hard refresh. How do I fix the hard refresh? So it will show on save.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. The Order Total Section goes white thats it. Then when I refresh browser everything shows with comment (by jonathan) section. So it works but not on first save no ajax refresh.

Comment: @Jonathan That means there are errors on your save function, enable the error log or check in debug logs